# Iterate through a Folder without touching the Subfolders

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

Hello i want to iterate through the Parentfolder Inbox. But and the messages which are in my Subfolder shouldnt be touched at all, to save time and ressources.

```
public static void listFirstTenItems() throws Exception {
    ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
    Folder folder = Folder.bind(service,  WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
    Folder subfolder = Folder.bind(service,  new FolderId(uniqueId));
    FindItemsResults<Item> findInbox = service.findItems(folder.getId(), view);
    FindItemsResults<Item> findSub = service.findItems(subfolder.getId(), view);

        service.loadPropertiesForItems(findInbox, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        service.loadPropertiesForItems(findSub, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        System.out.println("Total number of items found: " + findInbox.getTotalCount());
        for (Item item : findInbox.getItems()) {
            if (subfolder.getId() != item.getParentFolderId()) {
                System.out.println("sub==========" + item.getSubject());
            }
        }
```

But in this case, i do touch them.

Comment: You could use a [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and tell it to walk the first depth level only.

Comment: how do you want to iterate through the parent folder and the messages which are in the subfolder without touching the subfolder? Feel like I'm missing something, may need some clarification.

Comment: I just want to stay at the Parent folder's Level and see those messages, i dont want to see the subfolder's messages.

Comment: It's unclear because of the punctuation in your question. Do you want the messages from the subfolder or not? Or do you want only those from the main foler? Or both?

Comment: you say "I want to iterate through the parentfolder inbox and the messages which are in my subfolder" but according to your comment you don't want to see the messages in the subfolder?

Comment: I made it clear now (edited it). I dont want the messages form the subfolders

Comment: @deHaar im trying to figure out how it works btw

Answer (score 0):

So all you need to do then is remove the code that enumerate the items in the Subfolder, EWS will only let you enumerate items in one folder at time so remove that code all together as it serves not purpose to the use case your asking about eg

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
Folder folder = Folder.bind(service,  WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
Folder subfolder = Folder.bind(service,  new FolderId(uniqueId));
FindItemsResults<Item> findInbox = service.findItems(folder.getId(), view);

    service.loadPropertiesForItems(findInbox, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
    System.out.println("Total number of items found: " + findInbox.getTotalCount());
    for (Item item : findInbox.getItems()) {

    }
```

Also depending on what you doing and what properties you need to access the following line may or may not be necessary

```
 service.loadPropertiesForItems(findInbox, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

Comment: In this case, my software iterates through the items in the inbox folder and the items in its subfolder

Comment: So your question make no sense "Hello i want to iterate through the Parentfolder Inbox. But and the messages which are in my Subfolder shouldnt be touched at all, to save time and ressources" contradicts "my software iterates through the items in the inbox folder and the items in its subfolder" If you don't want to process subfolder items then don't but what you said above make no sense based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    public static void listItems() throws Exception {

    ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
    FolderView view1 = new FolderView(100);
    Folder folder = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
    SearchFilter filterFolder = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName,"Posteingang");
    FindItemsResults<Item> findInbox = service.findItems(new FolderId(uniqueId),view);
    FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = folder.findFolders(filterFolder, view1);
    service.loadPropertiesForFolder(folder, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
    service.loadPropertiesForItems(findInbox, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

    for (Folder f : findFolderResults.getFolders()) {
        System.out.println("Displayname=====" + f.getDisplayName());
        for (Item item : findInbox.getItems()) {
            System.out.println("sub==========" + item.getSubject());
            System.out.println(item.getClass());
            counter++;          
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

}

Server is doing the work, not my Application.